# React Native how to import a docx file from assets

Tags: react-native

Any ideas on why this doesn't work:

```
import Timesheet from './Timesheet.docx'
```

Works in the web browser, it gets imported and I can use the url to access the file later in the code.

When I use expo on android it returns as "module not found, file not found error"

Any thoughts on how to correct this?

Comment: usually we can upload/ read files, Idk how it works in web. but in JS we can only import another JS/ CSS files

Answer (score 0):

you need to do something like this

in your assets folder create a index.js file then add the following (assuming your Timesheet.docx is in the same directory)

```
const timeSheet = require("./Timesheet.docx");
export { timeSheet };
```

In the file that need the timesheet

```
import { timeSheet } from './assets'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works. :).